# Hive query to get max of count

Tags: hive, bigdata, hiveql

My input file is like this:

```
id,phnName,price,model
1,iphone,2000,abc
2,iphone,3000,abc1
3,nokia,4000,abc2
4,sony,5000,abc3
5,nokia,6000,abc4
6,iphone,7000,abc5
7,nokia,8500,abc6
```

I want to write a hive query to get the max count of a particular phone.

output:

```
iphone 3
nokia 3
```

till now I've tried the following query:

```
select d.phnName,count(*) from phnDetails d group by d.phnName
```

and got output like this:

```
iphone 3
nokia 3
sony 1
```

Help me to retrieve only the max value.

Comment: Provided the answer as below, please check and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the query working

Input

```
1,iphone,2000,abc
2,iphone,3000,abc1
3,nokia,4000,abc2
4,sony,5000,abc3
5,nokia,6000,abc4
6,iphone,7000,abc5
7,nokia,8500,abc6
```

Working Query

```
select c.phnName, c.counter 
from 
(select d.phnName as phnName, count(*) as counter from phnDetails d group by d.phnName ) c 
join 
(select max(f.counter) as countmax from
(select cnt.phnName as phnName, count(*) as counter from phnDetails cnt group by cnt.phnName ) f) g 
where c.counter = g.countmax;
```

Not sure if it is optimized however it is working as expected

Output as below,
[image]

Solved using the steps as below, If it answers your question please mark it as answered

```
CREATE TABLE phnDetails ( id INT, phnName STRING, price INT, details STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' STORED AS TEXTFILE;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/training/Phone/phones.txt' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE phnDetails;

select * from phnDetails;


select d.phnName, count(*) from phnDetails d group by d.phnName;


select c.phnName, c.counter from 
(select d.phnName as phnName, count(*) as counter from phnDetails d group by d.phnName ) c ;

select max(f.counter) as countmax from
(select cnt.phnName as phnName, count(*) as counter from phnDetails cnt group by cnt.phnName ) f ;

select max(f.counter) as countmax from
(select cnt.phnName as phnName, count(*) as counter from phnDetails cnt group by cnt.phnName ) f ;

select c.phnName, c.counter 
from 
(select d.phnName as phnName, count(*) as counter from phnDetails d group by d.phnName ) c 
join 
(select max(f.counter) as countmax from
(select cnt.phnName as phnName, count(*) as counter from phnDetails cnt group by cnt.phnName ) f) g 
where c.counter = g.countmax;
```

Comment: Thanks for marking my solution as answered, can you also vote up on my solution. Thanks for the quick confirmation