# How to use Max function on the output of count fucnction in Hive

Tags: mapreduce, hive

How to use `Max` function on the output of `Count` function. I have a table `candidates` with column as `candidatenames` as below

```
AAA  
BBB
CCC
BBB
AAA
FFF
AAA
AAA
```

I want output as below :

```
AAA 4
```

Since the `AAA` appeared maximum times `4`. How to get this output in hive?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hive query to get max of count](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24756744/hive-query-to-get-max-of-count)

Comment: I followed that link  but i think there must be some more simpler way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Hive windowing functions; you can read about them [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics).

**Query**:

```
select candidates, c
from (
    select candidates, c
        , max(c) over () max_c
    from (
        select candidates, count(*) c
        from db.table
        group by candidates ) x
    ) y
where max_c = c
```

**Output**:

```
candidates    c
AAA           4
```